# How to get extended properties of sql table in Entity framework (EF6)?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6, t4, edmx

I am working in VS-2013. I've added `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` containing:

1. EF Designer from Database,
2. Code First From Database

Connected to some of the tables in my database, it generated `tt` file with partial class and add annotation on every field of tables *as below*:

### ms_item_cat.cs

```
public partial class ms_item_cat
{
    public ms_item_cat()
    {
        ms_items = new HashSet<ms_items>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int pk_icat_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string icat_name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string icat_image_path { get; set; }
}
```

It does not show some extended properties that I've added to table e.g. Description, etc

below script is to show those extended properties:

```
select p.*, t.*
from sys.extended_properties p
inner join sys.tables t on p.major_id = t.object_id
where class = 1
```

Comment: And is your question that you want to see these extended properties in your object?

Comment: Yes, I want to show *extended* properties of SQL-table in `model.tt` T4 template file.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to retrieve my extended properties from the Db this way:

1. Add via Nuget Tiraggo library (`Install-Package Tiraggo.Edmx`). It brings access to some useful metadata in edmx file.
2. Add listed below references and namespaces to your *.tt file (some of them can be redundant for your purposes, but I needed all of them). I've added them between
   `<#@ include file="EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>`
   and
   `<#@ output extension=".cs"#>`

   ```
   <#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)TiraggoEdmx\TiraggoEdmx.EF.dll" #> 
   <#@ assembly name="System.Configuration" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Serialization" #>
   <#@ import namespace="TiraggoEdmx_v3" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
   ```
3. Then create an instance of db context with a proper connection string (you can do it somewhere near with instantiation of `typeMapper`, `ef`, `code` etc.)

   `var dbContext = new DbContext(yourConnectionString)`
4. Using Tiraggo library create an instance of edmx object. (edmxLocation is a path string to `edmx` file)

   `Edmx edmx = Edmx.Load(edmxLocation);`
5. Add static method to the end of *.tt file

   ```
   <#+ public static string GetExtendedProperty(DbContext context, string schema, string tableName, string columnName, string propName) {
        var query = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(string.Format("SELECT value FROM fn_listextendedproperty (NULL, 'schema', '{0}', 'table', '{1}', 'column', '{2}') where objname = '{2}' AND name = '{3}'", schema, tableName, columnName, propName));

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
   }#>
   ```

So, this method will retrieve an extended property from a table's column by name.

6. Inside `foreach` loop create an info object to get metadata for a concrete entity

   `var entityInfo = new TiraggoEntityInfo(edmx, entity.FullName);`
7. Retrieve an extended property value by calling a static method:

   ```
   string extendedPropertyValue = GetExtendedProperty(dbContext, entityInfo.StorageInfo.Schema, entityInfo.StorageInfo.Name, edmProperty.Name, extendedPropName);
   ```
8. Here is my full [template](https://gist.github.com/primez/78f1694569f24dc7cc335f181f9c9cd0). I've removed some code and the template could be in an uncompilable state, but you can see the usage of code there.

P.S. Hope, it will help. Sorry for improper formatting